# Render new on form error does not change URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in my Rails app with a very straightforward controller and if the form cannot save, I'd like to render `:new` to show the errors:

```
def create
    @health_profile = HealthProfile.new(health_profile_params)

    if @health_profile.save
        redirect_to :somewhere_else
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

This works great, but the URL goes from `/health_profiles/new` to `/health_profiles` following the attempt to create a record.  Is there a way to call `render :new` and have the URL reflect that the user is at `/health_profiles/new`?  If they were to refresh the page while the URL shows `/health_profiles`, it would load the `:index` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  You basically have three options:

1. You can [use JS to change the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/152786) after you re-render the new view.
2. You can change your `render` to a `redirect_to` but you'll lose the errors in `@health_profile` so you'd have to rely on the `flash` to show your errors.
3. You could change all your routes so that you can POST/PUT to the `new` route and put some conditional logic in your `new` action to branch based on the `request.method`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are submitting a form (to URL which is in "action" attribute of form). This is normal. Don't change the URL.